# coldfusion debugging information on production server

Tags: performance, debugging, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

We have a performance monitoring service for our ColdFusion 9 site so I can see when our server is slow to respond to a request.  However, I can't figure out much information on how to debug what's causing it to be slow besides what server is handling the request and the total page request time.  Ideally, I'd like to see the debugging information that can be enabled in the CF administrator to a file. (I can tell if it's the performance monitoring making the page request by its user agent.)

I found this [post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/659-determine-how-long-your-coldfusion-page-has-been-running-using-getpagecontext.htm) by Ben Nadel and thought there might be some more debugging information that I could pull from GetPageContext() but no luck so far.  **Anyone know any tricks on how to get the debugging information so I can log it from a production server?**

Thanks!

Comment: Your best friend would be to invest in FusionReactor. This will tell you exactly what's going on and where w/o implementing a custom solution. Also if you have Enterprise Edition, the CF Admin will show you some information to work with as well.

Comment: You can also look at Active Queries which might give you more information.

Comment: Have a look at the debug template files. That should give you a push in the right direction. Having debugging switched on is a significant performance hit though. Be warned.

Comment: Why has this been voted to close? And why did the person making the vote not have the decency to elaborate so as to help jessieloo make whatever perceived improvements are necessary?

Comment: It wasn't me, but since I can see the selected reason and jessieloo can't, I will say what I saw.  Too broad.

Comment: *I'd like to see the debugging information that can be enabled in the CF administrator* Is it actually enabled on the server? I do not believe you can access that information if debugging is disabled (which is typical in a Prod environment, because enabling debugging incurs a big performance hit, as Adam mentioned).